# how can i add and list a item to cart when checked a check box?

Tags: angularjs

I need some thing like bellow.When i click on checked box that should be add to the cart with which item i have checked all the details should be list on the cart.How can i acheive it?

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCart" >
<div ng-repeat="x in names">
<input type="checkbox" name="item">{{x.item}} {{x.price}} </input>
</div>
<div>
 <h1>Cart</h1>
        <div>Ex. Order Summary 100 
        //here i need to show the order price </div>
             <div>
           EX.  1.xxx Rs.10
                2.yyy rs.90
        //Here i need to list the items which are checked on the above 
        </div>
        </div>
            </div>
    <script>
    angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('MyCart', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('AngularJs-Response.jsp').success(function(response) {
            $scope.names = response;      
          });     
    }]);
    </script>
```

Comment: Your questions in not clear. You need to post controller ot describe more specific what you want to achieve. Seems you want that someboday will write controller instead of you

Comment: what i want to achieve it is .when i check a checkbox that item should be list in cart with details ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="startCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="x in names">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isSelected" ng-change="value(item.isSelected,x)"/>{{x.name}} {{x.price}}
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div>Selected Item</div>
    <div ng-repeat="y in selectedItems" ng-show="selectedItems.length>0">
        {{y.name}}----{{y.price}}
    </div>
    <div ng-show="selectedItems.length<=0"> No item selected </div>
</div>
```

Your angular code,

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("startCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.names=[{name:"mobile",price:"100"},{name:"Laptop",price:"200"},{name:"bag",price:"50"}];

$scope.selectedItems=[];    
$scope.value=function(isSelected,item)
{


        if(isSelected==true)
        {
            $scope.selectedItems.push(item);
        }
        else
        {
                console.log(item.name);              angular.forEach($scope.selectedItems,function(itemRmv,$index){
                if(itemRmv.name==item.name)
                {
                    $scope.selectedItems.splice($index,1);
                }
            })
        }
   }
});
```

Working fiddle,
http://jsfiddle.net/zqpxtbzo/